# New review feature proposal: auto-load the next review when the review queue is empty

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

It would be really cool if, when I get the "This queue has been cleared!" message,  I could instead get a "This queue has been cleared! Waiting for more items..." message; then, the next item loads automatically, rather than me having to reload the page.  Just a thought.

Comment: Love the idea, but queues with review locks would need to not lock for users like this, because you could just have the tab open and not notice that you need to review it for hours.

Comment: Yes... I imagine locks should only last a few minutes anyway.

Comment: Added feature request; when a review pops up, the title changes like the question pages and chat pages do. That way you know you have one pending!

Comment: Good, but when I am already looking at an empty page, there is no need for a notification... Just load the next item.

Comment: and / or heading on to other queues that you are eligible to access automatically - that's exactly what I'll do manually anyway...

Comment: This is a dublicate of [Real-time updates for new review tasks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148784/171881).

Answer (score 17):

Auto-loading the next item? No. Just having a page open is not a guarantee that a user is actually there and ready to review, and they should not be getting assigned new review items.

A far better approach would be to simply notify the user that there are new review items available, which could be coupled with [Bradley's title bar change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278838/new-review-feature-proposal-auto-load-the-next-review-when-the-review-queue-is#comment126618_278838) to indicate there is something you can do. This way, if they are inactive, they don't end up getting assigned review tasks when they can't complete them. They actually have to come back to the page and indicate to the system that they are ready to continue reviewing.

If at that point all the review tasks have already been assigned or completed, then the system can simply indicate that. "Looks like all those tasks have already been assigned! Waiting for more items..."

I'm not sure implementing all of this is actually *worth* the development time, but that is up to Stack Exchange to decide.

Comment: When I am already looking at an empty page, there is no need for a notification... Just load the next item. There is never a guarantee that the user is actually there; there should be a timeout on there already, right?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski It is not possible to determine if the user is actually looking at the empty page, though. It could be minimized, in another tab, or they could just plain not be at their computer. There is a timeout, but we shouldn't even start the timer without knowing the person is there to begin with. It doesn't make sense. What if a review item keeps getting continuously assigned to inactive reviewers, and goes for hours without actually being reviewed?

Comment: Timeout should be a few minutes--I'm guessing there already is one and that's all we need.

Comment: @animuson Of course there is. You can bind to keyup, keydown, click, mousemove, touchstart, touchend, scroll, and possibility resize event listeners.